Anime with two pilots test-flying spacefighters
I saw this on Teletoon in the late 90's- it revolved around three characters who'd known each other since childhood- a woman and two men, the latter two being military pilots. Each of the pilots were chosen to test fly one of two space fighters designed by competing companies, and whichever craft was deemed superior would be bought by the military.
At the beginning the pilots were fighting off alien attackers in fighter craft that could transform into robots with humanoid form.
I think it was two or three episodes, each episode probably between an hour and a half to two hours long.

It sounds like Macross Plus, a 4 episodes OVA (later re-edited as a 120 min movie)
It is set in the Macross/Robotech universe (but it seems that even the international version was under the Macross label, so I don't think it has a version in the Robotech franchise)
from Wikipedia:

Military test pilots and former childhood friends, loose cannon Isamu Alva Dyson and the Zentradi mixed race Guld Goa Bowman, are selected to each pilot a new aircraft (Shinsei Industries' YF-19 & General Galaxy's YF-21) for Project Super Nova, to choose the newest successor to the VF-11 Thunderbolt variable fighter which is currently still in use by the U.N. Spacy military forces. Their own personal grudges end up disrupting the tests, and begin to wreak havoc on the program

So you have the two pilots who are flying two prototypes of different companies. The prototypes are airplanes that can transform into robot.
I don't remember a fight against the alien at the beginning of the story, but it could be a scene from the testing (the two main characters used to argue even during the test flights) or maybe a flashback.

Isamu's in a fight at the very beginning and his reckless behavior in it is what gets him transferred out of his squadron into the test program.
